# DD WRT - Is there any option(SNMP /CLI) to get temperature of the router without using web interface?

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, telnet, snmp, dd-wrt

The dd-wrt firmware is installed in the router. I can able to ssh/telnet to the router also I can able to snmpwalk to the router. How to get router temperature using SNMP or CLI (ssh/telnet) which is shown in web GUI?

Comment: Did you read the documentation at http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/SNMP ? According to that article, there is no monitored OID for temperature.

Comment: @Jolta - I had read that document. Yes. There is no support in SNMP. But by looking at this thread, we can create some custom snmp values. Link http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=1054. So I'm  looking for a solution like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the way to get temperature of the router via CLI

`cat /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-0/0-0028/temp_input`

Link : [getting temperature and voltage of router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=37460)

Comment: On my dd-wrt router the temperature is in /proc/dmu/temperature and is in tenths of degrees C so 701 is 70.1 C.

Comment: On my DD-WRT v3.0-r35244 it is in file "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp" and looks to be out to the thousandth degree C, i.e. 62145